# Spring Boot - Best way to manage multiple exception / advice class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have several entities in a Spring Boot project, and for each of them I've written an exception class like so:

```
public class Item1NotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    Item1NotFoundException(Long id) {
        super("Cannot find Item1 with ID " + id);
    }
}

public class Item2NotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
        Item1NotFoundException(Long id) {
            super("Cannot find Item2 with ID " + id);
        }
    }
```

To go along with these exceptions, I've also written corresponding advice classes:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Item1NotFoundAdvice {
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(Item1NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    String item1NotFoundHandler(Item1NotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

And I've written an almost identical class for `Item2NotFoundAdvice`. As you can see, this code is highly redundant, and I was wondering what the best way to handle that is. Can I make a generic class for NotFound exceptions and corresponding advice classes to avoid redundant code? I'm not totally sure how I would go about that so any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `@ExceptionHandler` annotation can receive an array of `Class<? extends Throwable>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Just do:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ Item1NotFoundException.class, Item2NotFoundException.class })
```

Both exceptions will be handled by the same method.

Of course, you'll need to create a super type to handle both of these properly. Maybe a `NotFoundException` and then extend it from `Item1NotFoundException` and `Item2NotFoundException`, then, you can just do

```
@ExceptionHandler({ NotFoundException.class })
```